# Getting react/jsx-runtime error whiile running reactflow v11 version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-flow

`failedModules=sg-lineage-ui/js/sg-lineage-ui:Script error for "react/jsx-runtime"`

[image: React/jsx-runtime]

Already tried adding latest version of following things to package.json, which also didn't work:

```
  // ... rest
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.1",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this solution.

1. Update react, react-dom , react-scripts,
2. Uninstall previous dependencies of (react-flow-renderer)
3. remove node_modules , package-lock
4. install reactflow and other dependecies

please let me know if it not working or not